# Detecting ajax requests in selenium

Tags: c#, ajax, selenium

I am testing a single page app using selenium. I want to test to make sure that the app is only going back to the server when it needs to.

Is there a way in selenium to assert that no ajax requests to have occurred or that an ajax request has occurred and examine the ajax URL?

I am testing it at the moment by looking for the presence of a loading div, but this isn't what I actually want to be testing and it isn't very stable when testing on a local machine as the request sometimes outpace the test execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way present in WebDriver to detect your ajax request. See this issue.
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=141

But I can think of a work around.
Ask your developers to put a hidden div in the page source. Whenever they make an ajax call, ask them to update this div with a flag.

With WebDriver, you can easily read the flag of this Div and put your assertion.

You can also use built in WebClient libraries present in C# or java to achieve this thing.

This approach is described in detail in this blog.
https://rogerkeays.com/how-to-get-the-http-status-code-in-selenium-webdriver

If you just want to see if there is any ajax request occured, you can use javascriptexecutor class in webDriver. see the code below

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsScript = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
if(!(Boolean)jsScript.ExecuteScript("return jQuery.active == 0"))
retrun "ajax request occured";
```

Comment: Another approach is to obtain HTTP request and response headers via an embedded proxy.. See this link http://www.supermind.org/blog/968/howto-collect-webdriver-http-request-and-response-headers

Comment: This is a bit of a shame it doesn't support this better, but I don't really want to put DOM in just because i want to test it.